# IDE independence for source code - e.g. outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, ide

Recently I posted a question here on Stack Overflow, looking for some instruction on how to create a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file with dependencies in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

When I posed the question it quickly became obvious that I had poorly worded my question, and that it was confusing people who were responding, but that mishap brought up a point of interest I would like a little explanation for. So when I posted my question on how to do this in Eclipse I almost immediately got the response “Switch to [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), don’t rely on your IDE to do the work of a build tool”. This seemed a little evasive rather than helpful to me, especially considering I had mentioned that I was already using [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) to generate a JAR file for my projects. When I asked why, I got the response back “Because your code should be able to be built independently of the IDE in which it was written”.

So first off, in what way is having the ability to create a JAR file, with its dependencies either in the JAR file, or alongside it in a library folder making my code dependent on the IDE?

My code, with or without a dist directory still contains an *src* directory, with a typical Java source directory structure. This seems like a non sequitur. I feel that if I’m say working with a class library, and making some small changes and need to deploy to a development machine to test, I should be able to simply build a JAR file with all the dependencies easily in my IDE to deploy it someplace.

Having that ability is a build step, not a design step. It doesn’t change the structure of the source code directories, or anything about the code at all. It doesn’t create any partial classes, or other sneaky Visual Studio type stuff that is designed solely for the IDE I’m using; it's just requesting a JAR file with a valid manifest, and its dependencies. Is it really that much to ask of an IDE, or do I have this wrong?

It also seems to me that any change from one IDE to another is going to require some conversion work. Nothing about the code I’ve written in Java explicitly states where a given assembly is, and assuming that it’s not some API whose location on disk is added to an environmental variable during an install, you will always have to resolve these references manually.

And correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn’t the Java compiler enforce the directory structure of the source code (throwing NoClassDef type exceptions if it's not right), and therefore the IDE (at least for Java) is built around that requirement?

I also feel that a change in IDE is a rare event. People get comfortable with their tools and don’t just randomly decide to start using a whole new IDE, for the same project, in the same language. Other circumstances need to pressure a person into the change (new technology or whatever).

I would also think that the likelihood of a number of developers working at the same place, in the same language, and using multiple IDEs, is pretty much non-existent. Every place I’ve worked the entire development teams uses the same set of tools, where the development team is working on the same sort of projects. Android developers are using Eclipse, [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) developers are using Visual Studio, etc. I understand that it happens, but in my experience a change in IDE usually means converting to whatever new version of the same IDE was recently released, and usually it comes with some type of backward compatibility, or a conversion wizard.

I’m not trying to be facetious, nor take a stab at the people involved in my earlier post, I’m legitimately interested in their reasoning. Given the number of upvotes their answers receive, it would appear that most of the community agree, and in the interest of not being a sheep, please help me understand.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Projects can benefit hugely from being built on an independent build/CI server. This is usually reason enough to make your project independent of IDE.

Comment: Given that your last question was a long gripe about how much you hated Eclipse, I'm would be surprised if you didn't see the value in IDE independence in your code structure.

Comment: Agreed Paul, but as I had mentioned I am using Ant. The ant build scripts I wrote for my IDE could easily be deployed to our build server. I still dont see how that makes my code IDE dependent.

Comment: @Perception, this isnt helpful, and it wasnt a gripe. I simply mentioned that I dont like eclipse upfront. I didnt go on about it.

Comment: *I also feel that a change in IDE is a rare event*. It probably is but the choice of a Java IDE among coworkers can differ a lot. Some prefer eclipse, some Netbeans and some prefer IntelliJ IDEA. Using maven (for example) makes it very easy to use different IDEs. All dependencies are there instantly. You may not switch IDE yourself but it *is* easy to use different IDEs with maven. Ant does not give that flexibility. +1 btw for a great "story".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally want to have a way to build the jar from outside the IDE from an automated build tool because it makes for a repeatable, automated process. Let's say you build your jar from Eclipse and you do it by including your source code and a lib directory. Then someone else goes to build it, and they forget to include the lib directory. It could be difficult to track down problems as your build gets more complex.

If you're running code on a build server, for example, there is no ide, so there needs to be a way to build it automatically. You could of course roll your own scripts, but there are tools dedicated to making this a lot easier - namely gradle, maven and ant (in the java world anyway).

You can always use that build script from within your IDE but there needs to be a way to build without the IDE, and all builds should be consistent.

These tools like maven also do more than just build, they help to manage dependencies. The use repository managers to store artifacts your project needs, so you don't need to worry about having a lib folder and manually managing your dependencies. You just say what you want and the build tool figures out how to get it.

Being able to build quickly is important too. Running a build script is a whole lot faster than doing manual packaging.

Hopefully this has given some insight into why others have recommended using build tools. It's a good idea, and any serious project really needs them.

Comment: Well thats the thing that got me, I am using Ant, or at least the Ant builder for the eclipse IDE. Are the build scripts for the Eclipse Ant plugin build scripts different from Ant I say... have deployed to a build server?

Comment: If you're actually calling the same script in your IDE that you are on your build server, then you're not really using your IDE to build, but rather you're using the IDE to kick off your build script (which is perfectly fine). But if you're doing anything other than that, like right clicking on a source package and selecting "Create Executable Jar" or something similar, then your build is no longer repeatable.

Comment: Then it must have just been a miscommunication, because I even tagged my original question with ant, and eclipse. I just wanted to know how to set up a dist directory using the ant builder configurations in eclipse / or with eclipse itself. :/ Must work on communication skills.

Comment: Thought about this a little more, and I think what your saying is that its not really that the source is dependent on the IDE, but that the build step is repeatable. If I use an IDE's internal crap to build my code, there is no guarentee that another developer could rebuild my source in the same manner potentially introducing bugs, while using a build server with Ant, Maven or the MS build stuff ensures that all the code submitted to it conforms to whatever requirements it has, thus making the build repeatable. This I understand :D

Comment: Mark, exactly. Being repeatable is the key.